# Dúvida em sistema de notícias

Tags: php, html

Eu fiz um sistema de noticia, ai na index.php aparece um breve resumo da notícia, ai quando a pessoa clica em "Ver mais" ela vê a notícia completa. Porém o "Ver mais" é um 'href'. E eu não sei bem lidar com metodo GET em php.

Código que tá na index.php:

```
<div>
<?php
$noticias = listaNoticia($conexao);
foreach ($noticias as $noticia){
?>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading"><?=date("d/m/Y",strtotime($noticia['data']))."  -   ".$noticia['titulo'] ?></div>
<div class="panel-body">
<?=substr($noticia['noticia'],0 , 60)?><a href="noticia-visualizada.php?id=<?=$noticia['id']?>">Ver mais...</a>
</div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
```

A notícia ta sendo salva em um banco de dados, através de um Painelzinho que eu criei. Porém quando a pessoa clica em "Ver mais", dá "NOT FOUND". Queria saber se tem como utilizar metodo post nesse caso, ou qual a solução para gerar a página com a ID da noticia...

Código da página noticia-visualizada.php:

```
<?php
include ("conexao.php");
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "select * from sistemanoticias where id = $id";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao,$query);
$visu = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
?>
```

Comment: onde está seu select?

Comment: Olha o edit, coloquei la

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro verifique se o trecho:

```
<?=substr($noticia['noticia'],0 , 60)?><a href="noticia-visualizada.php?id=<?=$noticia['id']?>">Ver mais...</a>
```

Está linkando corretamente com o id da noticia, senão tente colocar um `echo`

```
<?php echo substr($noticia['noticia'],0 , 60); ?><a href="noticia-visualizada.php?id=<?php echo $noticia['id']; ?>">Ver mais...</a>
```

E na página `noticia-visualizada.php`
O código está correto, depois de pegar o id com `$_GET` você vai buscar no banco as informações da notícia e formatar no `HTML`. 
Teste o trecho para printar a noticia:

```
<?php
include ("conexao.php");
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM sistemanoticias WHERE id = ".$id;
if ($result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query)) {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row['id'], $row['titulo']); //ou
        echo "Id: ".$row['id']." - Titulo: ".$row['titulo'];
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

---

**GET vs. POST**

`GET` e `POST` criam uma matriz (por exemplo, matriz (chave => valor, chave2 =>
valor2, chave3 => valor3, ...)). Esta matriz contém pares de chave / valor, onde as chaves são os nomes dos controles do formulário e os valores são os dados de
entrada do usuário.

Tanto `GET` como `POST` são tratados como `$_GET` e `$_POST`. Estes são superglobais, o que significa que eles são sempre acessíveis, independentemente do alcance - e você pode acessá-los de qualquer função, classe ou arquivo sem ter que fazer nada de especial.

`$_GET` é uma matriz de variáveis passadas para o script atual através dos
parâmetros de URL. As informações enviadas de um formulário com o método GET
são visíveis para todos (todos os nomes e valores de variáveis são exibidos no
URL).

`$_POST` é uma matriz de variáveis passadas para o script atual através do método HTTP POST. As informações enviadas a partir de um formulário com o método
POST são invisíveis para outros (todos os nomes / valores são incorporados no
corpo da solicitação HTTP).

Comment: Olha meu edit. Fiz a conexao com o banco de dados para buscar a notícia. Porém continua dando not found. link que ta sendo gerado: http://site.com.br/noticia-visualizada.php?id=7

Comment: Agora foi. Muito obrigado